# I am using ffmpeg in android but taking much time to crop the video

Tags: android, android-studio, video, ffmpeg, crop

```
String[] commondForCropingVideoFast = {"-i", "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/sample.mp4", "-vf", "crop=" + 1080 + ":" + 1600 + ":" + 0 + ":" + 350, "-strict", "experimental", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/cropped.mp4"};
```

I am using this command right now, how can i make it fast??

Comment: might be the speed you get as a result is the fastest right?